# Multiple Default Routes in ASP.NET MVC to different Default Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have multiple controllers with different actions (no "Index" actions). The actions I consider "default" actions, are named differently. **I want to create default routes for their names** and have the first available action (from my list of default actions) executed if only the controller name is provided in the route.

So, for example, I have the following actions which I want to consider **default** and want checked for their existence in a controller in this order:

```
List() 
Draw()
ViewSingle()
```

The routing should somehow search for /{controller} and then take the first available action from the list above as default action, e.g.:

```
/ControllerA     -> ControllerA.List()
/ControllerB     -> ControllerB.Draw()
/ControllerC     -> ControllerC.ViewSingle()
/ControllerD     -> ControllerD.Draw()
/ControllerE     -> ControllerE.List()
```

Is this possible? I tried creating additional Default actions like this but couldn't get it to work:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default1", "{controller}/{action}", 
 new { controller = UrlParameter.Optional, action = "List" } 

routes.MapRoute("Default2", "{controller}/{action}", 
 new { controller = UrlParameter.Optional, action = "Draw" } 

routes.MapRoute("Default3", "{controller}/{action}", 
 new { controller = UrlParameter.Optional, action = "ViewSingle" }
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got something wrong about the default route. Those controller and action parameters are there for convention. If URL has a controller name in it, it will route to suitable controller. Same thing is true for Index methods. It just provides a default value for that.They are already optional and that's why. I think you don't need routes here: You could try to place your default functions in Index methods and it would work.Just to be clear:

```
public class ControllerA:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return List();
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
    //List function
    }
}


public class ControllerB:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Draw();
    }

    public ActionResult Draw()
    {
    //Draw function
    }
}
```

I think it would work. But if you want to go on with creating routes, you create each route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default1", "ControllerA", 
 new { controller = ControllerA, action = "List" }
```

Notice that ControllerA is not in curly braces,it's a static text. So you create routes for each controller. Keep controller naming convention in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Narsil. You should write a constant to url. -like controller name- 'cause MVC cannot resolve this routes and cannot figure out what you want to show.

eg.

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "ControllerA/{action}", 
 new { controller = "ControllerA", action = "List" } 

routes.MapRoute(null, "ControllerB/{action}", 
 new { controller = "ControllerB", action = "Draw" } 

routes.MapRoute(null, "ControllerC/{action}", 
 new { controller = "ControllerC", action = "ViewSingle" }
```